# DC.JS data-grid render React component

Tags: reactjs, dc.js

I'm working in a dashboard inside a React App and I used the React + DC.JS (https://github.com/LightTag/dcjs-in-react) as a guide. So far, so good.

Now I was required to add some new info in a component that used to be a dc.js dataTable so when the user click in a row, it would expand and show more data. My idea was to use the dataGrid instead and inject an material-ui ExpandPanel inside the HTML function of the dataGrid. Since the documentation says you can use any template engine inside it, I thought it would work.

Well, it doesn't work. I tried use an external function to the render the elements, explicit call React.createElement, put it inside parenthesis for the JSX, but all I got is a bunch of ''[object Object]''.

Any ideas of how to render React Elements inside a DC.js DataGrid?

Comment: Hi Daniel, unfortunately when the `dataGrid` talks about using a template engine, they are talking about engines that produce HTML *strings*. The chart is going to paste the string content as the `innerHTML` via d3's [selection.html](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.0/README.md#selection_html). The pathetic `[object Object]` is what you get when javascript tries to coerce an object to a string.

Comment: If you only need static content, you could figure out how to convert your results to a string. If you want serious React features, I think you'd need to first render the chart with blank content (`.html('')`), then in a `pretransition` handler select each of the blank elements and render React into it. Happy to work with you on this if you produce a simple example (e.g. jsfiddle, bl.ock) to start with.

Comment: Hello @Gordon, thank you. In fact what I was looking for is to keep the whole app using the same ui library. I'm able to make it work with static html and some use of jquery (for the box expansion).
The other option I was thinking is to create my own "chart" and use chartRegistry with a render and redraw implementation, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Glad you got something working! I believe it is possible to have a React component which is not implemented in React but contains other React components, but this stuff gets tricky. Pretty sure the wrapper component would need to deal with it somehow. The alternative would be lots (and lots) of react roots, which would be a big mess.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to **dcjs-in-react**, btw! I've only started messing around with React in the past few months, but putting the crossfilter into a context seems like the right model.